# perl parsing cgi parameters

Tags: perl, cgi, mod-perl

I remember reading somewhere that it's possible to pass arguments to a perl cgi script as such: 
`www.example.org/cgiscript/arg1/arg2/arg3`

I don't remember where I read it and searching didn't help me, so can anybody tell me if this actually works and if yes, how? Is this a mod_perl thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If a CGI script is called from a URL of the form:

```
http://example.com/path/to/script.cgi/foo/bar
```

then the path `/foo/bar` will be available in the environment variable `PATH_INFO`.

If you're using CGI.pm, this is also available in `$q->path_info`. If you're using mod_perl, `Apache2::RequestRec` has the same method.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there a reason why it's not "standard"? Any big drawbacks about this approach?

Comment: HTML `<form>` elements will pass arguments in a query string, so that's the de facto "standard" way of passing arguments to a script. You also have to use absolute paths when loading subresources from a script configured to use this, as any relative paths will be relative to the last part of the query string.

Comment: Can you expand on the last sentence? Does the script then "think" it runs in /script.cgi/foo/bar? I want to use this method to determine which content to display as it seems more clear in the URL than ?lang=foo;page=bar

Comment: Example: If you reference an image as `<img src="image.jpeg">` from `http://example.com/script.cgi/path/info`, the browser will try to load it from `http://example.com/script.cgi/path/image.jpeg`, which probably isn't correct.

Comment: Is it possible to work around this by using chdir or altering the PATH_INFO after parsing? or should that be avoided?

Comment: No. Path resolution is handled by the browser, which has no idea what's going on behind the scenes. You can use a `<base>` element in the HTML document, though.

Comment: One last (and a bit subjective) question, would that be considered bad style?

Comment: Would what be considered bad style? If you mean using PATH_INFO… depends on what you're using it for

Comment: I mean using PATH_INFO just to have a clearer URL and fixing the directory with a <base> tag. by clearer I mean `www.domain.org/script/EN/foo/bar` instead of `www.domain.org/script?lang=en;1=foo;2=bar`

Comment: Using PATH_INFO: Good. Using `<base>`: Best avoided; use absolute URLs instead.

Comment: Thanks for the extended help